# How do you update float data type in SQL column to hold numbers with upto 20 scale

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I have a SQL table with a column having float data type with default precision. 
I want this column to hold data with upto 20 digits after the decimal point.

How do I update existing column to do this?

Comment: Please say which variant if SQL you are asking about.  There are _incompatibilities_ between them.

Answer (score 1):

*SQL Server*: The literal answer here would be "you cannot". If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql), you'll see that the `float` type only supports two precisions - either 7 or 15 digits.

Answers provided so far all seem to be advocating a switch to a different datatype ([`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)) but don't highlight that this comes with its own drawbacks - notably that the `decimal` type supports a far smaller *range*. `float` can support a range from - 1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308 whereas `decimal` only supports a range of ~ -10^38 to 10^38 (and that, only if you are using a `0` scale). If using a scale of `20` then the range is limited to ~ -10^18 to 10^18.

Comment: No.  `DOUBLE` goes up to 308; `FLOAT` goes up to 38.  They, unlike `INT` and its friends, do not go higher when `UNSIGNED`.  `DECIMAL` can be up to `(65,0)` (1e65) and down to `(...,30)` (sort of 1e-30).

Comment: @RickJames - what on earth are you talking about? I admit my answer is [tag:sql-server] specific, but based on other questions from this poster, that doesn't seem an unreasonable assumption. There is no `double` (nor `unsigned`) in SQL Server and `float`, as you can see from the documentation I've linked to, is a data type which supports a range up to 308.

Comment: I'm quoting MySQL and IEEE 754.  I don't know about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumndecimal decimal(38,20)

decimal(precision, scale)
```

its mean left side = 18, right side = 20

Comment: No, precision is 38. If you want to say something about how many digits are to the left of the decimal point, be my guest, but don't *misuse* the terminology that is in all of the documentation. If you say `decimal(38,20)` then the precision is 38, not 18.

Comment: yes precision is 38(i mean that lefts side has 18 digit) but you can't insert in left side more than 18 digit, am i right?

Comment: i have changed my comment to "left side right side"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much value You want to store to the left of the decimal point. Lets say only number from 0-9 and 20 digits on the right.

```
Alter table tablename altercolumn columnname(21,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put decimal(precision, scale), replacing the precision and scale with your desired values.

ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName decimal(24,20)